# How do you fill the modal dialog on maximize in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, modal-dialog

I have a Search Results web part that pulls the most recent 5 items from a SharePoint list. Whenever you click one of these items in the web part, a modal opens and displays the list content.

However, when you maximize the window, the content does not dynamically fill the modal, it stays in its position as if the modal was not maximized.

I am also curious as to how you can dynamically set the modal to size to the content when it opens. Is this possible without having to go to jQuery? I really want to use jQuery as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to specify the height and width in option object

Like this

```
    var options = {
title: "yourTitle",
url: "yourUrl" };
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Hope it help to you.

Comment: Hi Nikolay. Thank you for responding. Where would this be added? How would this dynamically resize to the content?

Comment: this code must be added to place where you created modal dialog for item. Of course if you have access to javascript code to your web part.